# The probability that $x$ was sampled from the distribution with parameter $\mu$ is $P(\mu | x )$ or $P(x | \mu)$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Assume that we observe data point $x$. The probability that it was sampled from the distribution with parameter $\mu$ is which one: 
$P(\mu | x )$ or $P(x  |  \mu)$?

To me $P(x  |  \mu)$ makes more sense, but the slides claim $P(\mu | x)$.

---

[image]

Image from slide 26 [here](http://l2r.cs.uiuc.edu/~danr/Teaching/CS446-15/Lectures/10-LecSemi+EM.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the observation of data point x *is given* in this case, it will fall on the right side of the conditional probability: P(μ|x).

One can read P(A|B) as the "probability of A occurring, given that B has occurred." In your case, P(μ|x) would read as the probability a data point was sampled from distribution μ<sub>j</sub>, given that the data point was x<sub>i</sub>.